# How to get selected P tags as a node in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have select the multiple paragraphs in the editor. When i use the code `ed.selection.getContent({format:'html'})` then i can get the strings of selected texts. But i need the selected paragraphs as a Node(DOM elements)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code :

```
var allSelectPara = [];
var blocks = editor.selection.getSelectedBlocks();
tinymce.each( blocks ,function(block){
    if( block.nodeName === 'P'){
        allSelectPara.push(block);
    }
})
```